# Array Formula for text search

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have used this array formula to find true/false. The formula is only considering the text in the first cell

```
{=isnumber(search(G2:G7,A1))}
```

Comment: Why an array formula at all? Are you trying to determine whether *any* of the values in G2:G7 are within A1 (case-sensitive)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to determine if any of the words in G2:G7 is within A1. Also it does not have to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an extra layer of processing so that the formula does not halt at the first result of the [ISNUMBER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-586532CC-9888-4CA0-98B8-C874E4C8A087). A [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUM-function-043E1C7D-7726-4E80-8F32-07B23E057F89) wrapper should be sufficient.

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2:G7, A1)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Any non-zero result will mean that at least one of the terms in G2:G7 is within A1.

The CSE could be avoided by substituting a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) for the SUM.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2:G7, A1)))
```

The [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) is not case-sensitive; the [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) is case-sensitive.